# SelectNodes Always returning the 0 count

Tags: c#, xml

SelectNodes always returning the 0 count even the it has the value.

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>
    <Configurations xmlns="DEH_Common.Schemas">
      <sftpConfiguration>
        <file>
          <filedetails>
            <fileext>csv</fileext>
            <DataContentDetailId>1</DataContentDetailId>
          </filedetails>
    </file>
    </sftpConfiguration>
    </Configurations>
```

C# to read the nodelist....

```
XmlNodeList nodeList = xmlDoc.DocumentElement.SelectNodes("//Configurations/sftpConfiguration/file");
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's because of using namespace in your `xml`, You should add namespace to `xmlDoc and also no need to use`DocumentElement` This code would be work:

```
var nsmgr = new XmlNamespaceManager(xmlDoc.NameTable);
nsmgr.AddNamespace("a", "DEH_Common.Schemas");
XmlNodeList nodeList = xmlDoc.SelectNodes("//a:sftpConfiguration/a:file", nsmgr);
```

Comment: It Worked. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

In your XML `DocumentElement` is the Configurations node, so your XPath should be `sftpConfiguration/file`

```
XmlNodeList nodeList = xmlDoc.DocumentElement.SelectNodes("sftpConfiguration/file");
```

Comment: wrote a quick sample and `nodeList.Count` returns `1`. Had to remove the xmlns attribute and changed the encoding to utf-8 tho

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
xmlDoc.DocumentElement.SelectNodes("/Configurations[@*]/sftpConfiguration/file");
```

Comment: I got it. It's related to the namespace